# How to add meta tag for utf-8 in html created from xml and xslt files

Tags: java, xml

i got html files correctly but in that html i need to add meta charset="UTF-8" after html tag opened. How can i do this in run time via java

Am using the following java code to convert xml to html via xsl

```
public class TransInfoHtml 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
try {
    TransformerFactory tFactory=TransformerFactory.newInstance();

  Source xslDoc=new StreamSource("/home/dev702/Desktop/cadgraf-sample-xsl/CadgrafNITF.xsl");
  Source xmlDoc=new StreamSource("/home/dev702/Desktop/cadgraf-sample-xsl/Cadgraf_NITF.xml");

  String outputFileName="/home/dev702/Desktop/cadgraf-sample-xsl/cadgraf.html";

    OutputStream htmlFile=new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
    Transformer trasform=tFactory.newTransformer(xslDoc);
    trasform.transform(xmlDoc, new StreamResult(htmlFile));
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (TransformerException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: I am converting xml to html with the help of xsl. Your are asking me to add this directly into the files but i need that to be done via code

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that in runtime? Why not just adding this to your XSLT template as part of the output?